# Win7 XP mode install fails with cryptic error

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

Trying to install XPmode on Win7 Professional 64-bit SP1, but getting an error.

I downloaded XPMode, Virtual PC and the update as specified here: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx.

When I open XP mode for the first time it goes into the setup ("Setting up Windows XP Mode for first use..."; pick your VM password, etc.), then it runs through the progress bar until almost the end (99%?).  At that point I get the error:

`Could not complete Setup.  Please try again.`

Whats going on here?  I've uninstalled Virtual PC and xpmode, and reinstalled in several different orders, no luck.  Is there some log file that will tell me whats happening?  Theres nothing showing up in the Event log that I can find.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Take a look on this [MS Supoort](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/xp-mode-could-not-complete-setup-please-try-again/afdf1764-ae77-40cd-a8f2-6f54887b4bfa?tab=MoreHelp) may be it helps you. Also have you tried the hotfix which is provided in answer.

Comment: What is your computer model and motherboard ?

Comment: @harrmc -Computer is a custom build, motherboard is Gigabyte 990FXA-UD3.

Comment: @avirk -Yes, tried hotfix as mentioned in comments to the answer below.

Comment: So now take a look on that article and ask freely if any error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing XPMode after performing a clean boot:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and execute `msconfig`.
2. In the **General** tab, choose **Selective startup** and uncheck **Load startup items**.

   [image: screenshot]
3. In the **Services** tab, check **Hide all Microsoft services** and click **Disable all**.

   [image: screenshot]
4. Click **OK**, then **Restart**.

(images from [Microsoft Support: How to troubleshoot a problem by performing a clean boot...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135))

Comment: a normal restart is all that I needed

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to have an AMD bulldozer CPU/APU there's a Hotfix for that:

Microsoft KB2519949: [You cannot install Windows XP Mode on a Windows 7-based computer that has an AMD Bulldozer-based multicore processor installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519949)

> When you have an AMD Bulldozer-based multicore processor installed on
>   a computer that is running Windows 7, you cannot install Windows XP
>   Mode. Additionally, you receive an error message that resembles the
>   following:
>
> "Could not complete Setup. Please try again."

Comment: I didn't even think of that.  Listed as Zambezi, but since "...Zambezi is based on Bulldozer microarchitecture..." http://www.cpu-world.com/Cores/Zambezi.html, it might work!  How the hell did you find this?  Trying it now.

Comment: -No dice.  Same error.

Comment: -Any other ideas along these lines?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all bootable CDs or DVDs from your DVD drive (virtual or real). The XP Mode VM might accidently try booting off of that instead of the virtual harddisk image. Found [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprovirt/thread/02c9e716-9f46-4535-ad8c-68abba255c2d).